# PlantUML - how to define the order in which the element are drawn?

Tags: plantuml, c4-model

In below plantuml [code](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/NO_B3i8W44NtVCM4lIIjwD8K-mak2GjiYJ65eG6wCCP_Twg93sOnYtFkdMIwN6mgI_0iJrUSRR81ZdQOBYakEFRHnmGbMSoa79QVr133797OgToy0phHiWy31NS6y0q1LwBX11__M0aftr4QhQHeJ1sXPilPIukjgUixq8osWLhiIQotj3MRWpuRrZaSrqUV), i am defining `[a] -> [b]` after component A, still it is getting rendered before (i.e left of) component A. I want `[a] -> [b]` to be drawn after (i.e to the right side of) component A. How can i set this up.

```
@startuml
skinparam BackgroundColor transparent
skinparam componentStyle uml2

component A {
   component "A.1" {
}
   component A.44 {
      [A4.1]
}
   component "A.2"
   [A.3]
   component A.5 [
A.5] 
   component A.6 [
]
}

[a]->[b]

@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: By *after*, do you mean to the right of?

Comment: right.. @Fuhrmanator.. i mean to the `right` of component `A`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't like the result (it's ugly and not logical), but here's something:

```
@startuml
skinparam BackgroundColor transparent
skinparam componentStyle uml2

' define details for hidden component to wrap [a]->[b]
skinparam component {
  bordercolor<<hidden>> transparent
  stereotypeFontSize 0
}

component A {
   component "A.1" {
}
   component A.44 {
      [A4.1]
}
   component "A.2"
   [A.3]
   component A.5 [
A.5] 
   component A.6 [
]
}

' wrap inside a hidden component
component " " <<hidden>> {
  [a]->[b]
}

' hidden connector going up (which is not actually up, but lays out the group to the right)
" " -up[hidden]- A
@enduml
```

[image: PlantUML Diagram]

**EDIT**: A perhaps simpler answer is that both groups have to have some same-level ranking with links. You can add it by making hidden links between the elements in A, and the second part will naturally be laid out to the right:

```
@startuml
skinparam BackgroundColor transparent
skinparam componentStyle uml2

component A {
   component "A.1" {
}
   component A.44 {
      [A4.1]
}
   component "A.2"
   [A.3]

   component A.5 [
A.5] 
   component A.6 [
]
   A.1 -r[hidden]->  A.2
   A.2 -r[hidden]-> A.3
   A.2 -[hidden]-> A.5
   A.3 -[hidden]-> A.6
}

[a]->[b]

@enduml
```

[image]